# Simple increment/decrement program in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I am writing a simple addition subtraction program with two buttons. One button increments by one and the other decrements by 1. The program works fine if I remove my onclicklistener methods. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
  package com.newboston.thefirst;

   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.os.Build;

   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter=0;
    add= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    sub= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSub);
    display= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is "+counter);
        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your total is "+counter);
        }
    });
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();

    }
}


     /*   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
     }

     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
    * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
   public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
   }

  }
```

These are the errors that I am getting:

```
03-24 03:31:38.592: I/Process(361): Sending signal. PID: 361 SIG: 9

03-24 03:38:44.952: I/dalvikvm(389): Could not find method 

android.content.pm.PackageManager.getActivityLogo, referenced from method 

android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>

03-24 03:38:44.952: W/dalvikvm(389): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 312: 

Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getActivityLogo 

(Landroid/content/ComponentName;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;

03-24 03:38:44.952: D/dalvikvm(389): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x008b

03-24 03:38:44.962: I/dalvikvm(389): Could not find method 

android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo, referenced from method 

android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>

03-24 03:38:44.962: W/dalvikvm(389): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 308: 

Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;.loadLogo 

(Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;

03-24 03:38:44.962: D/dalvikvm(389): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0099

03-24 03:38:44.972: D/dalvikvm(389): VFY: dead code 0x008e-0092 in 

Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> 

(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V

03-24 03:38:44.972: D/dalvikvm(389): VFY: dead code 0x009c-00a0 in 

Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> 

(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V

03-24 03:38:45.122: D/AndroidRuntime(389): Shutting down VM

03-24 03:38:45.122: W/dalvikvm(389): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 

(group=0x4001d800)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start 

activity ComponentInfo{com.newboston.thefirst/com.newboston.thefirst.MainActivity}: 

java.lang.NullPointerException

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at 

android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at 

java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at 

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 

Method)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at 

com.newboston.thefirst.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at 

android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  ... 11 more
```

**EDIT**

XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context="com.newboston.thefirst.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Your total is 0"
      android:textSize="30sp"
      android:gravity="center"
     />
    <Button
      android:layout_width="200sp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="Subtract one"
      android:id="@+id/buttonSub" />

    <Button
       android:layout_width="200sp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="Add one"
       android:id="@+id/buttonAdd" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You're derefrencing a null pointer.  It looks like the button id you're searching for doesn't exist.  Are you loading the right layout?  And if so, post your layout xml

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException 03-24 03:38:45.132: E/AndroidRuntime(389):  at com.newboston.thefirst.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)

Comment: I think problem is with xml file, are you sure you have declared buttonAdd and buttonsub because for textview you used textview1 but for button you haven't used button1 and button2

Comment: I think Siva and Gabe are likely correct. You must have defined buttonAdd somewhere for this to compile, but it's probably not in your layout activity_main. findViewById will return null if it can't find the id you specified in the layout you're using.

Comment: @CharlieCollins,Siva,Gabe  you are right..but if this the case then her code will not even compile.

Comment: @KetanAhir As I said above buttonAdd must be defined somewhere to even have that resource id (R has it), but it's not in the layout  currently being used, hence NPE. (If buttonAdd is defined anywhere, it's in the R class and it can be referenced and things will compile fine, but that' doesn't mean the layout currently being used has that view.)

Comment: I was using a different xml file. I replaced activity_main by fragment_main in my java code. But my application still crashes. Let me post the fragment_main.xml code

Comment: @PriyaKar if buttons are in fragment_main.xml then get their reference in onCreateView of fragment not in activity.

Comment: @CharlieCollins Thank you for pointing the mistake out. I did replace my code but still my application crashes. I have pasted my xml code for fragment_main.xml Can anyone tell me what I am still doing wrong?

Comment: @KetanAhir I edited my activity_main file instead. I copy- pasted all my code from fragment to activity_main. Will that work?

Comment: KetanAhir and @CharlieCollins Thank you so much.. I copied my code in activity_main and tried running it and it worked! My first app build SUCCESSFUL.. Thanks again guys

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a null value here that's why null pointer is being thrown:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();

    }
```

You should try

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
// leave it blank if you don't intend 
// to do anything if savedInstanceState is not null
}else{
 // your codes here ..
}
```